# C# Excel get range of cells visible on the screen

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

I am trying to, Merge the visible cells such that the first sheet acts as introduction page with just once cell and has the text centered. 
So by visible, I mean the cells visible on the users screen. So if my monitor has a different size/resolution then the visible cells are different in number/range.

How do I get range of the visible cells?

Here is what i have tried.

```
  visibleCells = myRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);
```

I have tried different variations for myRange, but i am unable to get the range of the cells that are on the visible part of the screen.

Comment: Why not simply switch off the gridlines?

Comment: One more easy option. See [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/zoom.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim w As Window, r As Range
    Set w = ActiveWindow
    Set r = w.VisibleRange
    r.MergeCells = True
    r.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    r.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    r.Value = "Hello World"
End Sub
```